# Has my laptop been infected by APR virus?

Tags: networking, virus

Recently, I have experienced high latency on my home network. So I downloaded an APR monitor to see whether there were some problems. After some time, I found a MAC address, which sent lots of requests. The MAC address does not belong to any of my devices (including my modem).

So does this mean that my laptop has been infected?

This is the log:

```
2014/12/20 6:43:28  New station 192.168.0.15, hwaddr: A0-A8-CD-27-6F-D2
2014/12/20 6:43:28  New station 192.168.0.1, hwaddr: 6C-B0-CE-B9-75-C8
2014/12/20 6:54:16  New station 24.165.176.1, hwaddr: 00-01-5C-31-3B-C1
2014/12/20 6:54:16  New activity    00-01-5C-31-3B-C1, ip: 24.29.224.1
2014/12/20 6:54:16  New activity    00-01-5C-31-3B-C1, ip: 107.11.240.1
2014/12/20 6:54:21  New activity    00-01-5C-31-3B-C1, ip: 96.29.111.65
2014/12/20 6:54:28  New activity    00-01-5C-31-3B-C1, ip: 10.161.224.1
2014/12/20 6:54:30  New activity    00-01-5C-31-3B-C1, ip: 10.71.96.1
2014/12/20 6:54:30  Network scanning    Host 24.165.176.1 (MAC: 00-01-5C-31-3B-C1) generated 101 requests.
2014/12/20 6:54:41  New activity    00-01-5C-31-3B-C1, ip: 71.74.216.1
2014/12/20 6:54:53  New activity    00-01-5C-31-3B-C1, ip: 69.81.148.193
2014/12/20 6:55:24  Network scanning    Host 107.11.240.1 (MAC: 00-01-5C-31-3B-C1) generated 101 requests.
2014/12/20 6:56:50  Network scanning    Host 10.161.224.1 (MAC: 00-01-5C-31-3B-C1) generated 109 requests.
2014/12/20 6:56:52  Network scanning    Host 24.29.224.1 (MAC: 00-01-5C-31-3B-C1) generated 139 requests.
2014/12/20 6:58:15  Network scanning    Host 107.11.240.1 (MAC: 00-01-5C-31-3B-C1) generated 338 requests.
2014/12/20 6:58:24  New activity    00-01-5C-31-3B-C1, ip: 10.55.104.1
2014/12/20 6:58:55  Network scanning    Host 24.165.176.1 (MAC: 00-01-5C-31-3B-C1) generated 101 requests.
2014/12/20 6:59:55  Network scanning    Host 24.165.176.1 (MAC: 00-01-5C-31-3B-C1) generated 102 requests.
2014/12/20 7:00:48  New activity    00-01-5C-31-3B-C1, ip: 142.254.151.213
```

Comment: Didn't yo mean ARP virus and ARP monitor? To detect it get an offline live scan cd (like [avira rescue cd](http://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-rescue-system)) and scan your system.

Comment: Where are you running the monitor from?  What does `arp -a` give you on the same machine once you have run the monitor?  What modem are you using?  How are you measuring latency?